# Is it secure to share the GCM Key of my app to the third party vendor?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am integrating a third party sdk with my android app. They require GCM Key to be disclosed to them. Is it secure to share the GCM Key of my app to the third party vendor, or there are any security related issues?

Comment: Are you talking about the GCM sender ID, or the google API key?

Comment: I am talking about google API key.

Answer (score 1):

The Google API key is your property, it is better to not share it, but if the third party library uses GCM services to work properly you will have to provide it.

Comment: Are there any security issues related to it, if the GCM key is disclosed?

Comment: @SuchiJohari not really, but they could spam the hell out of your users who uses the app.

Comment: they could use any Google API in your name, including APIs with paying quotas